# How to get the x position with respect to content size and device width?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have these values:

- **iPhone** Width: 414
- `UICollectionView` Width: 414
- `UICollectionView` Height: 25
- `UICollectionView` ContentSize Width: 578
- **Scroll** to Position: 466
- **Custom View** Width: 112
- **Custom View** Height: 25

How to find a value (`origin.x`) with respect to `UICollectionView` width when scroll to the position is **466**?

**Additional Details**: I am moving a custom view to the scrolled position of a cell in `UICollectionView`. Even if we have more content size than the actual width of `UICollectionView`, we should fit the custom view in a position with respect to `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @hemange can you provide some code which I see and can some help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code // NOT TESTED

**EDITED**

```
let percentage = (self.collectionview.contentOffset.x * 100) /  (self.collectionview.contentSize.width -  self.collectionview.frame.size.width)
 let rightCorner =  (self.collectionview.frame.size.width *   percentage ) / 100

 yourview.frame.origin.x  =  rightCorner
 yourview.frame.origin.x -=  yourview.frame.size.width
```

**EDIT 4 Sep**

Add following code in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

```
if ([self.view viewWithTag:500000]) {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:500000] removeFromSuperview];
}

CGFloat xPos = ((scrollView.contentOffset.x) / (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width)) * (scrollView.frame.size.width - 112) ;

UIView *view = [UIView new];
view.tag = 500000;
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos ,self.collectionViewFrames.frame.origin.y + self.collectionViewFrames.frame.size.height, 112, 25)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[self.view  bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question more specifically, can you please check?

Comment: @Hemang Please check Edit 4 Sep and let me know if you have still issue

Comment: @Hemang For me it is working  Please copy pasted code in `scrollviewDidScroll` , I have  added  Full code as per your view , Please provide a problem you are facing

Comment: @Hemang You can check collection view scroll indicator and RED View

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for your constant efforts to my question. I have found the solution, I will post here later.